# Shouldn't the nlp tag be replaced with natural-language-processing?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems like [nlp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) should be changed to [natural-language-processing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-processing) and that [nlp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) should be used as a synonym of it instead because it is less apparent what [nlp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) is.

Comment: I agree that nlp is a poor tag. However, tag lengths are limited to 25 characters and "natural-language-processing" is too long. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Thomas Owens even just natural-lang-processing would be better, and while not especially intuitive, the poster would see it pop up as the only suggestion after typing out natu I think

Comment: @ThomasOwens recently tag length limit was [increased from 25 to 35 chars](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8606/31260) so this suggestion can be implemented as-is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [natural-lang-processing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-lang-processing)?

The reasons being that it's much clearer than [nlp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp), it's under 25 characters, and a user would (at least at present) see only this tag pop up after hitting `natu`.

Comment: I'm a little hesitant since "nlp" is the widely used abbreviation for natural language processing, but it seems the community is starting to favor this. If there aren't any serious objections or alternative ideas in the next couple of days, I wouldn't be opposed to forcing the synonym.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I agree that NLP is the widely used abbreviation for people in the know, but I'm more interested in helping people who *don't* know and whose interest might be piqued more by having it spelled out than by a cryptic acronym. I don't think the nlp community would mind as long as [tag:nlp] is a synonym (as far as I understand how that works).

Comment: NLP is also unfortunately shared with Neuro-linguistic programming

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**This tag has been renamed to [natural-language-processing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-processing)**

---

**Agreed**

Now that the maximum tag length has been [increased to 35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/351462), I don't see any reason why this tag can't be renamed to [natural-language-processing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-processing).